# Creating branch from tag (git) fails with maven-release-plugin:branch

Tags: git, svn, maven-release-plugin

We are trying to migrate a simple maven project from svn to git. We are using maven-release-plugin and the workflow is (currently) like something like this:

Working on trunk when happy create a release version and tag it with something like this:

```
trunk -> 2018.02.01-SNAPSHOT

release:prepare release:perform ...

tag -> 2018.02.01
trunk -> 2018.03.01-SNAPSHOT
```

For patching we create a branch from a tag:

```
git checkout 2018.02.01
mvn -B release:branch -DbranchName=release/2018.02 -DupdateBranchVersions=true -DupdateWorkingCopyVersions=false
branch -> 2018.02.02-SNAPSHOT
```

This works fine on SVN but on git we get the following error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building my-project 2018.02.01
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:branch (default-cli) @ my-project ---
[INFO] Verifying that there are no local modifications...
[INFO]   ignoring changes on: **/pom.xml.releaseBackup, **/pom.xml.next, **/pom.xml.tag, **/pom.xml.branch, **/release.properties, **/pom.xml.backup
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/hfm/git/my-project && git rev-parse --show-toplevel
[INFO] Working directory: /home/hfm/git/my-project
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/hfm/git/my-project && git status --porcelain .
[INFO] Working directory: /home/hfm/git/my-project
[INFO] Transforming 'my-project'...
[INFO] Checking in modified POMs...
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/hfm/git/my-project && git add -- pom.xml
[INFO] Working directory: /home/hfm/git/my-project
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/hfm/git/my-project && git rev-parse --show-toplevel
[INFO] Working directory: /home/hfm/git/my-project
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/hfm/git/my-project && git status --porcelain .
[INFO] Working directory: /home/hfm/git/my-project
[WARNING] Ignoring unrecognized line: ?? pom.xml.releaseBackup
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/hfm/git/my-project && git commit --verbose -F /tmp/maven-scm-112348369.commit pom.xml
[INFO] Working directory: /home/hfm/git/my-project
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/hfm/git/my-project && git symbolic-ref HEAD
[INFO] Working directory: /home/hfm/git/my-project
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.086 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-01-12T18:13:45+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/184M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:branch (default-cli) on project my-project: An error is occurred in the checkin process: Exception while executing SCM command. Detecting the current branch failed: fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I understand the error message `fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref`. It is because I checkout a tag in detached mode. But if I checkout into a new branch, then I will get 2 branches (one that I created manually and another which is created by the `release:branch` goal).

The question is, are we using the maven release plugin in wrong way? Or is it not meant to use it with git in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We decided to stop using the maven-release-plugin and instead do the same thing with the help of [build-helper-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/index.html) and [versions-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/). The steps looks something like this:

```
git checkout -b release/2018.02 2018.02.01

mvn build-helper:parse-version versions:set -DnewVersion=${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.${formattedVersion.minorVersion}.${formattedVersion.nextIncrementalVersion}-SNAPSHOT

mvn versions:commit

git commit -am "Bumped dev version for release branch."

git push
```